# CSS Cursor: Can it be a semi-transparent image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an effect when you place the mouse cursor over an **img** it glows in the small region where the mouse is.

**I acheive this by changing the cursor to a .gif when its over the img. I have used the CSS cursor attribute for the img, but the cursor image(a .gif I made in photoshop) is flat when it is supposed to be transparent.**

Is it possible to have a semi transparent cursor in HTML/CSS? Maybe I need to use a .cur file or maybe .ico?

Should I just hook the **onmouseover** event & place an img(with the transparent glow look) under the mouse as it moves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the alternative if you need the image to be animated, but using a 32-bit PNG instead (which you should prefer over GIF regardless `;)`) should work.

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own custom cursor.

Then apply this style:

```
.customCursor {
   cursor: url('mycursor.cur');
}
```